# Having trouble with in.nextDouble()

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to use the in.nextDouble() method in the below program designed to compute the average of a few numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value;
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a value, Q to quit: ");
    while (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
            value = in.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + value;
            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter a value, Q to quit: ");
    }
    double average = sum / count;
    System.out.printf("Average: %.2f\n", average);
}
}
```

This code works although I don't understand why. When I first use while(in.hasNextDouble()) I haven't initialised in to anything so why does the loop work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `in.hasNextXXX()` when there is no input, the `Scanner` **waits** for input.

So, it waits for you to enter a value in the first case.

It will exit as soon as you enter something **other than a double** (and press enter).

The doc of `Scanner#hasNext()`

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

This is true for all `hasNextXXX()` operations.

Comment: that makes more sense... you any doc link where this **wait** is explained?

Comment: @Jordi, it's the same with any stream, it wait's until it get's data or the stream is closed. Let me fetch the docs.